# replace alphabets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scikit-learn

I would like to replace the letters by their order number in the alphabet

Comment: What are you going to do for letters j, k and so on? What will be their corresponding value? 10, 11? If so, how are you going to differentiate 'k' from 'aa' (they will both be 11).

Comment: letters correspond to their order in the alphabet, aa = 1.1, k =11

Comment: II don't have a 2 letters, all are 3 letters values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import string

import pandas as pd

new_vals = {c: ord(c)-96 for c in string.ascii_lowercase}

df = pd.DataFrame({'Values': ['aaa', 'abc', 'def']})

df['Values_new'] = [''.join(str(new_vals[c]) for c in row) for row in df['Values']]
```

`df` is now:

```
>>> df
  Values Values_new
0    aaa        111
1    abc        123
2    def        456
```

Then you can go in and add your what-seems-like-decimal notation, although the logic there seems a little unclear to me (you have a comma listed above):

```
df['Values_new'] = [v[0] + '.' + v[1:] for v in df['Values_new']]
```

Result:

```
>>> df
  Values Values_new
0    aaa       1.11
1    abc       1.23
2    def       4.56
```

Comment: It's very close, is it possible to use all the letters to numeric ? h=8 for ex

Comment: sometimes I have only 1 letter